# C++ Linked Lists and Pointers to Pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, linked-list

First post but I have been a lurker for some time now :)

First, I am attempting to execute this skeleton code in Visual Studio 2015 and it should work as is according to my teacher so I am not sure what else could be wrong client side that may be causing that.

Finally, the overall issue here is I am not sure how to complete the remain commands. I understand the basic concepts of how the pointer to pointers work as well as the linked lists but not completely. My first issue is not helping either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Several

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct _node {
    int value;
    struct _node *next;
} node;

void append(node**, int);
void prepend(node**, int);
void lprint(node*);
void destroy(node*);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    node *head = NULL;

    append(&head, 1);
    append(&head, 2);
    append(&head, 3);

    prepend(&head, 0);
    prepend(&head, -1);
    prepend(&head, -2);

    lprint(head);
    destroy(head);

    return 0;
}

void append(node **head, int value)
{
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = (node*)calloc(0, sizeof(node));
        (**head).value = value;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp;
        for (temp = *head; (*temp).next != NULL; temp = temp->next);
        (*temp).next = (node*)calloc(0, sizeof(node));
        (*temp).(*next).value = value;
    }
}

void prepend(node **head, int value)
{

}

void lprint(node *head)
{
    node *temp;
    for (temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->value);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void destroy(node *head)
{

}
```

Comment: Look up `calloc` to see what the parameters are.  The first one is the number of elements to allocate, so you don't want to pass a 0 there.

Comment: I see, I changed it to malloc but it still seems weird since that was provided by the teacher.

Comment: You should not expect much from a teacher who tells you to use `calloc` in C++.

Comment: @Beta Just looking at the code, pretty much every line is C. Initialisation and deinitialisation functions; pointers to pointers; C standard library; typedefed structs. Probably an incorrectly tagged question... although VS only provides a C++ compiler these days I think.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to compile and run your code after changing this line:

```
    (*temp).(*next).value = value;
```

to this:

```
    (*temp).next->value = value;
```

When I ran it, it printed out:

```
1 2 3
```

... which is what I would expect, given that prepend() isn't implemented.

I could write an implementation of `prepend()` and post it here, but I don't want to risk doing your homework for you; instead I'll just describe how `prepend()` ought to work.

For the case where `head` is NULL, `prepend()` can do the exact same thing that `append()` does: allocate a node and set `head` to point to that node.

For the other case, where `head` is non-NULL (because the list is non-empty), it's pretty easy too -- even easier than the `append()` implementation.  All you need to do is allocate the new node, set the new node's `next` pointer to point to the existing `head` node (*head), and then set the `head` pointer (*head) to point to the new node.

The `destroy()` function can work with a loop very similar to the one in your `lprint()` function, with one caveat -- you have to grab the `next` pointer out of a given node (and store it into a local variable) *before* you free() the node, because if you free the node first and then try to read the next-pointer from the already-freed node, you are reading already-freed memory which is a no-no (undefined behavior) and will cause bad things (tm) to happen.